Error with Column Splitter in Sitecore SXA 10.2
We're using the out-of-the-box Page Structure Components in SXA (Sitecore 10.2). When we drag and drop the Column Splitter, it gets added correctly, but if we change the grid dimensions for column 1 and column 2, we encounter the following application error.

Error -

Please see the logs below for reference -
25872 13:30:55 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException
Message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (layout=".../*[@@name=&#39;Data&#39;]//*[@...").
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Can you check is there any datasource on the page components that has path something like this /*[@@name=&#39;Data&#39;]

The error in the logs indicates that the system detected a potentially dangerous Request.Form value due to the query in your component:
ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException
Message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (layout=".../*[@@name=&#39;Data&#39;]//*[@...").

This issue is likely caused by using a datasource query like:
query:$site/*[@@name='Data']//*[@@name='Gallery Folder']
This query is triggering request validation because of the special characters ([@@name='...']) being included in the form values.
To fix this, try simplifying the query to avoid those characters:
query:$site/Data/Gallery Folder
This should help prevent the validation error. Let me know if this resolves the issue.
